# Verifying precise address with geocoder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding, rails-geocoder

Basically I ask my users to enter their full address.
In my viewer it looks like:

```
<%= label_tag('Address') %> <br>
    <%= label_tag(:address_unit, 'Unit/Flat/Apartment Number:') %> <%= number_field_tag(:address_unit, current_profile.try(:address_unit)) %> <br>
      <strong><%= label_tag(:address_street, 'Street Number and Name:') %></strong> <%= text_field_tag(:address_street, current_profile.try(:address_street)) %> ie 51 Kennedy Street <br>
      <strong><%= label_tag(:address_city, 'Suburb/Town/City:') %></strong> <%= text_field_tag(:address_city, current_profile.try(:address_city)) %> <br>
      <strong><%= label_tag(:address_state, 'State/Province:') %></strong> <%= text_field_tag(:address_state, current_profile.try(:address_state)) %> <br>
      <strong><%= label_tag(:address_zip, 'Post/ZIP Code:') %></strong> <%= text_field_tag(:address_zip, current_profile.try(:address_zip)) %> <br>
    <strong><%= label_tag(:address_country, 'Country:') %></strong> <%= text_field_tag(:address_country, current_profile.try(:address_country)) %> <br>
```

In my controller, I basically concatenate these fields and then pass it to geocoder like:

```
  def address_check
    complete_address = ''
    if (params[:address_unit])
      complete_address += params[:address_unit] + ', '
    end
    complete_address += params[:address_street] + ', ' + params[:address_city] + ', '\
        + params[:address_state] + ', ' + params[:address_zip] + ', ' + params[:address_country]
    coords = Geocoder.coordinates(complete_address)
    coord_invalid = coords.present?
    return coord_valid ? nil : 'Address cannot be found, please correct your address'
  end
```

The purpose of this address check is to make sure user has written an existing address. The issue that I am having is, Geocoder accepts any address as long as zip code and country is provided. For example: `asdasd, asdasd, asdasad, 90503, USA` is an acceptable address.
My question is, is there a way to precisely look up for the address, such that if it can't be found, then no coords returned? By the way I use Rails 4.